# how to get customer id by custom attribute value

Tags: magento-2.1, customer-attribute

I need to get customer id before login by custom attribute value in Magento 2.1.5, for login by username.

```
$this->customerRepository->get($username);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please Try **below code :**

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $customerObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection');
    $collection = $customerObj->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                  ->addAttributeToFilter('your_attribute_name',$your_attribute_value)
                  ->load();
            
   $c_data=$collection->getData();
   $c_data[0]['entity_id'];
   echo $c_data[0]['entity_id'];
```

Comment: @Bapu  I have updated my answer please check.

Comment: Thanx deexit & manthan too

Comment: Before login  it secure or not?

Comment: How we can get customer attribute collection in magento 2? Because i want to show on catalog price rule form. How i can achieve this?

Comment: It always displays first record...seems it holds first record.